# angularjs service scope issue after directive event listener callback

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am trying to use an event listener in my angular directive along with a service.

I am having a scope issue as I want 'this' to refer to my service's 'this'.

Right now, in my service, 'this' returns:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" style='display:none'
multiple/>
```

and I would like to be able to access my service's local variable instead.

template

`<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" style='display:none' multiple/>
<button type="button" class="btn {{style}}" ng-click="pickFrom()">{{label}}</button>`

directive

```
function pickerLocalDirective(pickerLocalService){
    return {
        'scope':{},
        'link': function(scope, element, attrs){

            scope['label'] = pickerLocalService.label;
            scope['style'] = pickerLocalService.style;
            // pick method
            scope['pickFrom'] = function(){
                document.getElementById('files').click();
            }

            document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', pickerLocalService.handleFileSelect, false);
        },
        'templateUrl': 'components/picker/pickerLocal/pickerLocal.html'
    };
}
```

service

```
function pickerLocalService(){
    ...
    this.name = 'Local';
    ...
}
pickerLocalService.prototype.handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
    ...
    window.console.log(this);
    // NOT WORKING
    window.console.log(this.name);
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make a function that acts as a constructor, and stores instance variables as `this.someProperty` you need to invoke your function with the `new` keyword.

That being said, that's not how you make an angular service anyways.

From [the AngularJS docs on services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services):

> Services are registered to modules via the [Module API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module). Typically you use the [Module#factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module) API to register a service:
>
> ```
> var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
> myModule.factory('serviceId', function() {
>   var shinyNewServiceInstance;
>   //factory function body that constructs shinyNewServiceInstance
>   return shinyNewServiceInstance;
> });
> ```

In your case, you want your service to return an object with a `name` property, and a `handleFileSelect` method. You could do that like this:

```
// create a module
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

// register a service to it
myModule.factory('pickerLocalService', function() {
  // declare your variables
  var name = 'Local';

  // return an object with the properties you need
  return {
    name: name,
    handleFileSelect: function(evt) {
      // should work now
      console.log(name)
    }
  }
});

// create a directive that depends on your service
myModule.directive('pickerLocalDirective', ['pickerLocalService', function(pickerLocalService){
  // ... your directive 
}]);
```